# JWT token generated using jsonwebtoken library gives invalid signature in jwt.io

Tags: node.js, jwt, auth0

In short : the token generated using below code gives the correct headers and payload(when I paste the generated token in JWT.io).

It only works when I insert the secret and press the secret encoded checkbox in jwt.io. After that I get valid token.

But var token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKEY, signOptions);  this step should do the same thing I guess.

My code.

```
  var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    var payload = {
       "userId" : 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
       "iat" : new Date().getTime(),
    };
    var signOptions = {
      algorithm:  "HS512"  
    };
    var privateKEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; 
    var token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKEY, signOptions); 
    console.log("Token :" + token);
```

This gives me an invalid token but when i paste that token in jwt.io I get the correct Headers and Payload.
And if I insert my secret and press the checkbox I get the correct token.
What I am I doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you check the checkbox on jwt.io, it base64 decodes your secret. Since you don't base64 encode your secret in your code, you shouldn't check that box on jwt.io. Both tokens are correct, but for different secrets. If you want the same token that you got from jwt.io with the box checked, you can use this:

```
var decodedSecret = Buffer.from(privateKEY, 'base64');
```

Then use that to sign your token instead of `privateKEY`. However, this doesn't really make sense, as your key isn't base64 encoded to begin with.